# Filter out outliers dynamically using PERCENTILE

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm building a sales dashboard in PowerBI.

I have a Sales table.

My source of data is declarative, so I have a few extreme values caused by human errors and mistypes, etc.

Let's say I want to build a histogram with:

- On the X axis, the stock aging of any sales. Which is "how long the product has been in stock at the time of sale". It is given by the [Product_Age] column
- On values, the number of sales.

What I want to do is exclude the top 1% extreme values from my calculations (average, etc.) and vizualisations.

I've created a measure :

```html
SalesByAge_Adjusted = 
VAR TEMP =
FILTER(
    SALES;
    VAR StockAgingMAX =
        PERCENTILE.INC(
            SALES[Sales_Age];
            0,99
        )
    RETURN 
        SALES[Sales_Age] < StockAgingMAX
)
RETURN
COUNTROWS(TEMP)
```

It uses PERCENTILE.INC to get the 99th percentile of Sales_Age values in the current context and I try to use it as a filter.

However, it just won't work.
I can diplay the measure on its own. How many sales I have. But as soon as I drag and drop "Sales_Age" to summarize the values. It shows nothing.

Comment: You'll have to make a calculated column for this - and I would consider doing it in power query instead of DAX.  But you cannot filter with a measure. See my answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477462/how-do-i-filter-results-by-a-measure-in-power-bi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the following table as an example.

```
+-------+--------+
| Axis  | Values |
+-------+--------+
|     1 |   1067 |
|     2 |   1725 |
|     4 |    298 |
|     8 |    402 |
|    16 |   1848 |
|    32 |   1395 |
|    64 |   1116 |
|   128 |   1027 |
|   256 |   1948 |
|   512 |    790 |
|  1024 |   2173 |
|  2048 |   2025 |
|  4096 |    104 |
|  8192 |   1243 |
| 16384 |   1676 |
| 32768 |   1285 |
| 65536 |    806 |
+-------+--------+
```

For filtering the values that are out the 99% percentile I've created the following measure. Basically it gets an overall percentile without filter context and compares to each Axis value.

```
Filter = IF(CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC('Table'[Axis],0.99),ALL('Table'))>=MAX('Table'[Axis]),1,0)
```

In the visual of the chart, you use the filter measure to exclude your outliers

[image]

In this case, it will filter the last value of table: 65,536

Comment: Thanks! It works and it's way slicker than what I first intended to do. Instead of create duplicates "curated" version of existing measures, I can just enable this filter at the visual level. Great!